# Android Login with Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I've been following this tutorial. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

But when I'm tested the app through the real device, 
When I click on the Sign in button, a toast is appeared saying **"An internal error has occurred"**

Could you please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enable the Google+ API

Comment: Yes I did it in the Google api console

Comment: Can you check logcat, see if you are getting any exception?

Comment: have you create client id for your app in google console ?

Comment: No exceptions in Logcat. 
Yes I created a client id in api console.

Comment: Did you added the correct SHA1 key in the developer console ? You can see some of the comments in the tutorial that you are following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually 'Internal error' shows up if one of the following is wrong:

In **Google's Developer console website**:

1. You have created a project, but not enabled Google api

Inside the Project:

**Credentials**

1. SHA1 Code is not correct
2. Package Name is not correct

**Consent Screen**

1. The associated email address is missing
2. Product Name is missing

If all these are correct, it should work automatically....

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't updated the Consent Screen section. Thanks it worked.

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SHARE = 1000;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private PlusClient.Builder mPlusClientBuilder;
    private PlusShare.Builder mPlusShareBuilder;


// In your onCreate()
mPlusClientBuilder = new Builder(this, this, this);
        mPlusClientBuilder.setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PROFILE);
        mPlusClient = mPlusClientBuilder.build();
mPlusClient.connect();

// Overrides methods

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.disconnect();
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        btnSignIn.setText(getString(R.string.signout));
        textUserName.setText(accountName);

    }

// Signin Click event

btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signin))) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                } else if (mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signout))) {
                    mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
                    mPlusClient.disconnect();
                    btnSignIn.setText(getString(R.string.signin));
                    textUserName.setText("");
                    txtLoginAs.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                }
            }
        });

//onActivityResult

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SHARE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @SpringBreaker to whom you write this? nobalG, doesn't posted anything here